# É possível utilizar PHP para criar meta tags dinâmicas para SEO?

Tags: php, seo

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu utilizar o PHP nas metatags, como description, keywords...

Eu já utilizo no titulo: `<title><?php echo $titulo; ?>`. Posso fazer o mesmo nas metatags?

De:

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="descrição aqui, etc, etc...">
```

Para:

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
```

Comment: Sim, pode. Já tentou? ;)

Comment: Não, pois fiquei com receio de que algo desse errado.
A minha ideia é a mesma do <title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
Em cada página eu irei definir as variaveis $description e $keywords, e la no header irá buscar essa variavel. Assim, cada página terá a sua, certo?

Não sei se estou correto, mas leva alguns dias para que o google imprima esses novos valores em seus resultados, né?

Comment: O legal é instalar Xamp ou semelhante na sua máquina, assim pode rodar php localmente para testar a vontade

Comment: Eu já utilizo o Wamp! Acredito que dessa vez falei bobagem... é só eu testar as variaveis na metatag e exibir o código fonte de cada página pra saber se está alterando, não é?! que vacilo! rs

Comment: sim, exatamente

Comment: Poder fazer isso pode, mas tem que saber se realmente o Google e outros navegadores vão levar em consideração o conteúdo que tem nestas variáveis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Resposta

Pode utilizar sim.

## Mas porque?

Tanto o Google, como qualquer outro buscador ou navegador irá entender os dados da MESMA forma que entenderia se você definisse os valores diretamente no HTML.

Isso é conceito básico de PHP.

PHP é uma linguagem server-side, ou seja, roda do lado do servidor. Logo, antes que qualquer informação HTML seja enviada para quem quer que seja, ela será processada pelo módulo do PHP, que irá gerar um HTML completo e só depois irá enviar pro visitante / requisitante.

## Não entendeu ainda?

Vamos ilustrar.

1. O visitante acessa seu domínio e requisita o arquivo index.php (ou qualquer outro);

Seu arquivo index.php original é assim

```
<?php
    $descricao = 'informatica, hospedagem, criação de sites, cloud';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Meu site - Menino sagaz</title>
    <meta name="description" <?php echo "content='" . $descricao . "'"; ?>>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Seu servidor irá receber a solicitação e se tratando de um arquivo .php, irá acionar o módulo do PHP para que o mesmo interprete todo e qualquer código PHP do arquivo.

Então o módulo PHP faz seu trabalho e transforma seu arquivo index.php nisso

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Meu site - Menino sagaz</title>
    <meta name="description" content='informatica, hospedagem, criação de sites, cloud'>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Com arquivo pronto, ele envia o index.php para o visitante e todos ficam felizes.

PS: visitante pode ser qualquer um, seja o visitante (ôh), o Google, o Bing e até o Yahoo.

## Resumindo

Não importa se você fez seu site 100% usando echo pra gerar os HTML's e conteúdos. O visitante NUNCA vai saber como foi feito, porque ele sempre vai receber o arquivo pronto, já processado pelo módulo do PHP.

Answer (score 1):

O PHP como uma linguagem back-end irá entregar a página já renderizada para seus usuários e aos mecanismos de busca. Resultando no mesmo conteúdo que você iria reproduzir manualmente.